# Should I always replace backslashes with forward slashes in the paths for cross-platform development on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, gulp, cross-platform, chokidar

Once, my [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) watcher (wrapped to `gulp.watch()`) stops working. After experiments and debugging I found out that cause was double backslashes in globs:

```
gulp.watch([
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])
```

(Of course, I don't write absolute paths in above globs manually - I make it generated programmatically.)

I almost have not experience with UNIX-based operation systems, but I want my code works cross-platform. If below code works on each of Windows, Linux and Mac OS, I suppose that I should **always** transform backslashes to forward slashes in my Node.js programs - it the most safe way. Is my assumption right?

```
gulp.watch([
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/0_Development/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/1_Open/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])
```

Also, I found out that solutions like `path.normalize()` not always gives the desired result. Is `.replace(/\\/g, '/')` is **only save way to guarantee forward slashes** only in paths?

---

### Update: new experiment results

None of below ones works:

```
// --- 1
gulp.watch([
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)',
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)'
])

// --- 2
gulp.watch([
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)'),
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup\\**\\*.+(pug)')
])

// --- 3
gulp.watch([
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])

// --- 4
gulp.watch([
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\0_Development\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'),
  path.normalize('C:\\Users\\i\\projects\\test\\1_Source\\1_Open\\1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)')
])
```

But

```
gulp.watch([
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/0_Development/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)',
  'C:/Users/i/projects/test/1_Source/1_Open/1_Markup/**/*.+(pug)'
])
```

works.

Comment: Did you look at path.join to create your globs?  Or path.sep.

Comment: @Mark, I'll try what you said, but subject of this question is unified slash type selection.

Comment: Yes, both of those suggestions will insert path separators appropriate for whatever platform they are run on.

Comment: @Mark, I take some more experiments. `path.sep` and \ are not equivalent in Windows? Although `\` `path.sep` has same appearance, unlike `\`, `path.sep` do not escape next symbol in string....